# ¿Cómo soluciono el error "Error: Failes to find 'ANDROID_HOME'"?

Tags: android, cordova

Cuando hago un cordova build en el cli, me da este error:

> Error: Failes to find 'ANDROID_HOME' enviroment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include valid SDK directory.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: desconozco sobre este tema.. pero no te esta diciendo que te falta un variable dentro del Path?

Comment: instalastes el SDK de android?, lo agregastes al PATH de windows?, una manera de saber abre Win+R y escribe %ANDROID_HOME% si no te sale nada debes instalarlo o agregarlo al PATH de forma manual

Comment: esta agregado al path, no instalado. Donde puedo descargarlo?